# Remove comma from concatenated string for last cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Excel that has 10 columns. For each row there are different numbers of cells populated e.g.

[image]

My concatenated string is as follows for HTML emails

(" + Machine1 + ", " + Machine2 + ", " + Machine3 + ", " + Machine4 + ", " + Machine5 + ", " + Machine6 + ")

However I want the comma to not show after the last cell in the row (whether that be column 3,4,5,6).

This is what I get

**(TEST1, TEST2, TEST3 , TEST4, TEST5, , )**

I want to remove the two commas at the end. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel then use TEXTJOIN:

```
="(" & TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,A2:F2) & ")"
```

If not then you will need to use IF for each return and Mid:

```
=MID("(" & IF(A2 <> "",", " & A2,"") & IF(A2 <> "",", " & B2,"") & IF(C2 <> "",", " & C2,"") & IF(D2 <> "",", " & D2,"") & IF(E2 <> "",", " & E2,"") & IF(F2 <> "",", " & F2,""),3,999)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative without `IF`**

Just in addition to Scott's valid solution, I demonstrate an approach via the `REPT` function. Applied on a *cell containing a string*, it "repeats" its content & comma  once (indicated by `COUNTA()` equalling 1), whereas an *empty cell* results in a zero repetition which allows to omit not only the cell content but the comma, too:

```
="(" & SUBSTITUTE(REPT(A1&",",COUNTA(A1))&REPT(B1&",",COUNTA(B1))&REPT(C1&",",COUNTA(C1))&REPT(D1&",",COUNTA(D1))&REPT(E1&",",COUNTA(E1))&REPT(F1&",",COUNTA(F1))&"$",",$",")")
```

A simple `SUBSTITUTE` removes the last comma, wherever it occurs before the closing bracket ")".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it